# Prevent react-native-webview to open another app when clicking a deep link

Tags: react-native

In my react native app, I open a google search, showing me some links.
On my device I already have an app related to one of the links.
When I open this link, it opens the app.

I don't want this link to be opened in the app, I want to stay in the webview.

Using react-native-webview

How can I prevent this app to open ?

[image: example]

Comment: Hi @moooss, did you figured out how you can prevent it?

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't

Answer (score 1):

Basically, any click that opens in a new tab Webview will try to open that link in your mobile application if you have that application. For example, I was using Facebook in my Webview, and whenever I used to go to my save posts screen and click on one of my saved posts it used to open in my Facebook app. I solved this issue by setting setSupportMultipleWindows prop to false.

```
   <WebView
    source={{uri: 'https://www.facebook.com/'}}
    javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
    injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
    setSupportMultipleWindows={false} <==== Set this to false
  />
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on iOS. The documentation itself specifies that it only works for Android unfortunately. Any suggestions how to prevent apps from opening on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding that app's protocol to the `originWhitelist` prop of the webview? That way, instead of using the OS to handle the link, the webview will do the job.